# Create table type by name then add an arbitrary column?

Tags: dynamic, abap, rtts

I am attempting to write a class that can accept a table name, add a couple of extra columns for data ingestion purposes, then generate a CSV. I have it working for a table by sending in a table name as a parameter:

```
" Get the data dictionary object for the table
table_type ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( table ).
" Create a table description object with the line type
table_descr = cl_abap_tabledescr=>create( p_line_type = table_type ).
" Declare the internal table using the generic type
create data gt_data type handle table_descr.
```

This generic code gets me home to then create a SQL call via cl_sql_statement and fill the gt_data object. My question is:

Can I add a column to the generic type? I wanted to add a timestamp column to the front of the object as to when I have extracted the data from the system.

I also may want to run queries with a JOIN where I may need a single field from another table that the generic type doesn't handle, so I may need to add a single extra column. How can this be done?

Comment: You could use the method `CREATE_DYNAMIC_TABLE` of the class `CL_ALV_TABLE_CREATE`. It takes in a fieldcatalog and creates a data referenz for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youre pretty close to the solution already.
Using the **RTTS** classes.
There is an example in your ABAP system that does what you are looking for.

See ABAP `demo_create_data_via_handle`
The  [Docu](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abapcreate_data.htm) covers this process as well.

Here is a snippet from the Program.

```
METHOD main.
    DATA: struct_type TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
          dref        TYPE REF TO data,
          oref        TYPE REF TO cx_sy_struct_creation.

    DATA column1 TYPE c LENGTH 30.
    DATA column2 TYPE c LENGTH 30.

    FIELD-SYMBOLS: <struc>  TYPE any,
                   <comp1>  TYPE any,
                   <comp2>  TYPE any.

    cl_demo_input=>add_field( CHANGING field = column1 ).
    cl_demo_input=>add_field( CHANGING field = column2 ).
    cl_demo_input=>request( ).

    column1 = to_upper( column1 ).
    column2 = to_upper( column2 ).

    TRY.
        struct_type = cl_abap_structdescr=>get(
          VALUE #(
            ( name = column1 type = cl_abap_elemdescr=>get_c( 40 ) )
            ( name = column2 type = cl_abap_elemdescr=>get_i( )    )
                 )
                                               ).
        CREATE DATA dref TYPE HANDLE struct_type.
      CATCH cx_sy_struct_creation INTO oref.
        cl_demo_output=>display( oref->get_text( ) ).
        RETURN.
    ENDTRY.

    ASSIGN dref->* TO <struc>.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT column1 OF STRUCTURE <struc> TO <comp1>.
    <comp1> = 'Amount'.

    ASSIGN dref->* TO <struc>.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT column2 OF STRUCTURE <struc> TO <comp2>.
    <comp2> = 11.

    cl_demo_output=>display( |{ column1 WIDTH = 32 } { <comp1> }\n| &
                             |{ column2 WIDTH = 32 } { <comp2> }| ).
  ENDMETHOD.
```